# Incorrect query encoding when executing Hive from file

Tags: java, hadoop, encoding, utf-8, hive

I have a Hive query with CJK characters in a file like below:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name LIKE '日本語%';
```

And the file is encoded in UTF-8:

```
> file -bi query.hql
text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

If I execute it with Hive CLI, I can get expected result:

```
> /path/to/hive -f query.hql
some results here
```

Now I want to execute this query from Java. So I wrote some code like:

```
String[] cmd = new String[]{"/bin/bash", "/my/script", "/path/to/query.hql", "/path/to/output.txt"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
...
pb.start();
...
```

And `/my/script` looks like:

```
HQL_FILE=$1
OUTPUT_FILE=$2
/path/to/hive -f "${HQL_FILE}" > "${OUTPUT_FILE}"
```

I ran my Java program but got no output. I checked Hive log file and it looks like an encoding issue.

If I run `hive -f query.hql` via shell, the CJK text logged correctly in hive log:

```
> cat /tmp/myuser/hive.log
2016-02-29 11:27:40,303 INFO  [main]: parse.ParseDriver (ParseDriver.java:parse(185)) - Parsing command: ... name LIKE '日本語%' ...
```

But if I run via above Java program, the log looks strange

```
> cat /tmp/myuser/hive.log
2016-02-29 11:29:41,104 INFO  [main]: parse.ParseDriver (ParseDriver.java:parse(185)) - Parsing command: ... name LIKE '???????%' ...
```

I've been investigating this problem for half day but could not find any useful information.

I appreciate if anyone can give me some advice.

PS:

1. Hive Server is not an option. I have to invoke hive client via shell.
2. I'm using Hive 0.14.0.

Comment: From the command lines, this seems like a Unix-like system (Linux? Mac OS X? Other? Or is that Windows + cygwin?). What are the environment differences between your Java process and your command line?

Comment: The hive client and Java program are both executed from a CentOS 6.3.

Comment: Yes, however it does not mean that their environment will be the same! I am talking about the process's environment variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the Java program isn't writing the hql file itself, in the shell where the hive command works, run this command:

```
echo $LANG
```

You'll probably get something like `en_US.UTF-8`.

Take whatever value you get and modify your Java program to have this after you create the ProcessBuilder:

```
pb.environment().put("LANG", "en_US.UTF-8");
```

(Use whatever value you got instead of en_US.UTF-8)

If your Java program is writing the hql file itself, then there's something else to worry about too: when you open the file, you should specify UTF-8 encoding for output. How to do that will depend a bit on how you're opening the file.

Comment: Another option is to put this in your script before you invoke hive: `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: YES YES YES !   The `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in script works !  Thank you very much. But don't know why, the `pb.environment().put("LANG", "en_US.UTF-8");` solution does not work.
I `echo $LANG > /tmp/lang.txt` in `/my/script` before invoking hive and the output is an empty line.

Comment: The only thing I can assume then is that something is clearing out the ProcessBuilder's environment sometime before you call `pb.start()`. Are there any lines that look to be doing that?

Comment: Any chance that your `$HOME/.bashrc` or `/etc/bashrc` conf files have a hard-coded `export LANG=blah_blah` somewhere?